# Is there any way to monitor bluetooth traffic?

Tags: android, bluetooth

So, what I want is just to scan the environment and see if any packages are sent without pairing or connecting to a device. Just a general scan of bluetooth in the air and being able to see some of what comes up, like packages exchanged and maybe some information of them. Everything I've read so far is about pairing or connecting first.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I guess not, using the Android API. Maybe there is the option to connect to the device directly using native code.

Comment: What would this native code be? Thank you

Comment: It require special  Bluetooth hardware (or Bluetooth firmware). Also there are Bluetooth sniffing solutions for SDR.

Answer (score 0):

The question is old, but since nobody gave an answer I try to fill the gap.

Bluetooth is, because of its technical specifications (frequency hopping etc.), difficult to sniff. A monitor mode like in WiFi doesn't exist out of the box. You would need to scan all Bluetooth channels at the same time. And then there is the challenge that since you managed to detect something, you need to know the next hop (to which channel the devices jump next). There are commercial hardware that can do that. Also some open source projects come up like Ubertooth, but with less capabilities.

You could try to purchase an Ubertooth and play with it.